# Variable assignment is not allowed in a statement containing a top level UNION operator

Tags: sql-server

I have two very similar tables and am getting this error when running the following query:

> Variable assignment is not allowed in a statement containing a top level UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator

Please tell me how can I fix it?

```
SELECT @EID = [EId] 
FROM  [HR].[E]
WHERE @LName = ltrim(rtrim([LName]))
UNION
SELECT @EID = [EId]
FROM  [HR].[EArchive]
WHERE @LName = ltrim(rtrim([LName]))
```

Comment: Please tell us what you are trying to to, you can only assign a single value to a variable - your code doesn't guarantee only 1 result however.

Comment: Take a look for this query, if first query and second query both return EId, so which one you want SQL to assign to variable? union can't be use here, if you want to assign second query value when first one is empty, write to two lines instead of use UNION.

Comment: Why do you use the variables?

Comment: In case if you want the two `[EId]`s as result, remove the `@EID = `.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding anything else you are doing, or worrying about multiple hits etc, the query can be:

```
SELECT @EID = [EId] from (
  select Eid 
  FROM  [HR].[E]
  WHERE @LName = ltrim(rtrim([LName]))
UNION
  SELECT [EId]
  FROM  [HR].[EArchive]
  WHERE @LName = ltrim(rtrim([LName]))
) q
```